# Named Pipe in UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm using a named pipe server in my UWP app, but I cannot get a python client running from the console to connect.  Where is the location of this pipe?  And I think it has to do with UWP sandbox restrictions.  Looked around a lot but seems microsoft is just getting to this stuff.

```
# CS
new NamedPipeServerStream("LOCAL\MYPIPE");

# Python
f = open(r"\.\pipeLOCAL\MYPIPE", 'r+b', 0)
```

Comment: Try `"LOCAL\\MYPIPE"`

Comment: @squillman no luck.

Comment: Windows 10, version 1709:  Pipes are only supported within an app-container; ie, from one UWP process to another UWP process that's part of the same app. Also, named pipes must use the syntax "\\.\pipe\LOCAL\" for the pipe name.

Comment: I found this project made by somebody else which might be of help to you: https://github.com/hannesne/NamedPipesSample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So while some MSFT resources may claim that UWP supports memory mapped files, it does not.

That is unless you are willing to use the desktop bridge, but given the complexities there, including the requirement you use 32bit!, you might as well bridge over TCP.

This may change with NET Core 3 in Q1? 2019.

I hope if an MSFT employee reads this they can ask the right people why we can't have memory mapped files on side-loaded internal enterprise only apps.  No doubt a major impediment to UWP uptake.

Comment: I'd use an AppServiceConnection instead of TCP, but either would work

Comment: UWP supports pipes (with condition noted by @lindexi above). The ACLs have to allow the interaction between the two processes, though, and it's easier if the full-trust component creates the object (otherwise it's in a local namespace for the app-container). Or you can `DuplicateHandle` just fine.

Comment: My colleague has encountered a tough program similar with this one(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431348/ipc-uwp-c-sharp-pipe-client-fails-on-connect-c-server). It's namedpipe between a UWP client and C++ server. Could you take a look at it and give some opinions? Thanks! @PeterTorr-MSFT

Comment: NamedPipeServerStream("LOCAL\MYPIPE") fails in UWP

Comment: Win32 != 32 bit; Win32 ist just the OS API, which is used in 64bit programs as well

Answer (score 0):

I used `AppServiceConnection`

Covered by these tutorials (sorry for the link only answer but these tutorials are too long to paste here):

[Create and consume an app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Convert an app service to run in the same process as its host app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/convert-app-service-in-process)

In my C# console application I also needed to reference these two libraries from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753172/the-type-or-namespace-appserviceconnection-could-not-be-found) to make it work

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd
```