# The type or namespace AppServiceConnection could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, dll, uwp

I am having trouble getting a solution to compile on a new computer. The solution contains a UWP App that gets packaged with a Console Application. The UWP app communicates with the Console Application via an [AppServiceConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appservice.appserviceconnection).  The UWP app is able to create an instance of the `AppServiceConnection` class and compile just fine. However the console app seems unable to find anything related to the `AppServiceConnection` class. It throws the following error:

`The type or namespace AppServiceConnection could not be found`

Looking at the References section of the Console Application, I noticed that there are a bunch of DLLs that cannot be found. Included in those is the `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract` DLL which contains `AppServiceConnection`.

Looking at a coworkers computer which is correctly resolving these references, I learned that the DLLs were contained in the installation directory of .Net Framework `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1`  When I inspect this directory on my own machine, I notice that I do not have this assembly.

Why is this missing on my machine even though our versions of .Net Framework are the same? Is there something I am forgetting to install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference these two, and that's all.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd
```

If you choose from the suggestion list, **do not** reference `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd`, reference `Windows.winmd`.

[image]

Comment: I actually dont get any of those options on the list when mousing over the AppServiceConnection class. I did try to manually add a reference to Windows.winmd but found out one already existed. The console application targets .Net 4.6.1 so should I be adding references to .NETCore? I also noticed that if I create an entirely new console application, it seems to be able to use AppServiceConnection just fine.

Comment: Yes. Please refer to [this post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/). I cannot explain well enough why a Console app can reference a .NetCore library and most of all why it is required, but you should be able to find some blogs on this topic.

Comment: Thank you for the link! Unfortunately, I have added both references now but I am still unable to access AppServiceConnection.

Comment: I realized I was using the Nuget Package that is also mentioned in the blog post linked above. I created a new project, and added the references that kennyzx mentioned manually, and everything is compiling just fine!

Comment: When the problems continue even if those libraries are added check the project file. I had invalid path hint for my computer: <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll</HintPath>. Replaced '..\..\..\..\..\..\..\'  with 'C:\'.